# .N operator of data.table not accessible when present inside package's functions

Tags: r, data.table, package

I'm building a package in R, one of the scripts contains below function:

```
my_function <- function(dataset,column_name = "column_b"){
  data.table::setDT(dataset)
  dataset[,.(Count=.N), by = c(column_name)]
}
```

I get the error
`Error in .(Frequency = .N) : could not find function "."`

I even included data.table into Imports section of DESCRIPTION file. How do I make dot operator of data.table accessible when present inside a function in a package?

Comment: Have you also imported data.table in your NAMESPACE file?

Comment: The package has a vignette about it you might want to check out, eg here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html

Comment: Please note that the error is referring to `.`, the one before the opening parenthesis, and NOT to `.N`. `.` is just an alias `data.table` uses for `list`.

Comment: just need to do add `library(data.table)` to your session?